# css/javascript selected link style

Tags: coding-style, hover, hyperlink, border

i have some links that are surrended by some borders. on hover, the links are made white. my code:

#product_unavailable_types a:hover {

border-color: #fff;
   }

i would like that those borders will remain white after the selection also. i mean, if i click on that link, the borders will stay with the above style. and i have no idea how to do it.

any clue?

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching for the `a:visited` pseudo class.

That means:

```
#product_unavailable_types a:hover, #product_unavailable_types a:visited {
    border-color: #fff;
}
```

**EDIT**

If the link doesn't lead you to another page, try to put this in the `head` element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function highlight(link) {

        link.style.borderColor = '#fff';

    }

</script>
```

Then, add the `onclick` attribute to your `a` element, so that it looks like:

```
<a href="#test" onclick="highlight(this);">test</a>
```

Comment: On mouse out, now i see. Then you have to deal with javascript. Are you using some javascript framework like jQuery?